# Noise while altering audio data

Tags: python, audio, numpy, stream, real-time

I am playing audio with python and i don't understand why  i hear  noise on the ouptut when executing code like this:

```
import pyaudio  
import wave 
import numpy as np

f = wave.open('blabla.wav',"r")  
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  
# open stream  
stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(f.getsampwidth()),  
                channels = f.getnchannels(),  
                rate = f.getframerate(),  
                output = True)  
float_array = np.fromstring(f.readframes(10000000), dtype=np.uint16).astype('float32')
output = 0.9 *  float_array
stream.write(output.astype('uint16').tostring())
```

When i multiply by `0.9` i expect weakening a signal a little bit.  But where from this ouput noise came from ? 
I don't even add anything to initial data!

Basically i want to add two signals :

```
   output signal =  0.5 * the origin one  + 0.5 * shifted origin one
```

But i get mess out of this process, because even a multiplying  an original array make the signal near entirely  sound like a mess.

Can you point me out what am i doing wrong and how to make the formula

```
   output signal =  0.5 * the origin one  + 0.5 * shifted origin one
```

work right ?

Comment: How does it sound without the multiply?  You should be able to change the volume that way - if you can't, you probably have the samplewidth or numchannels in the output wrong.

Comment: without multiplying it sounds perfect: totally the same way like it does in multimedia player. I thought just like you that i could change the volume of the sound manipulating with audio data like this. But no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 16 bit PCM is usually signed.  Try using `int16` instead of `uint16`

Comment: Thank you! I could'not even think about this possibility!